# If a matrix $Q$ is symmetric and positie definite, is it possible to show that the matrix $Q-A^T(AQ^{-1}A^T)^{-1}A$ is also positive definite?

Tags: positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If I have a symmetric and positive definite $n\times n$ matrix $Q$ and a full row-rank totally unimodular $m\times n$, where $m<n$, matrix  $A$, is it posible to show that the matrix
 $$Q-A^T(AQ^{-1}A^T)^{-1}A$$
is also positive definite?

I have show that it is true when the matrix $Q$ has dimention $2\times 2$, by doing all the posible situations. Also, If $m=n$, I have that the matrix $Q-A^T(AQ^{-1}A^T)^{-1}A$ can be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix $Q - A^T(AQ^{-1}A^T)^{-1}A$ will generally be positive semidefinite. Let

$$M/Q : = Q - A^T(AQ^{-1}A^T)^{-1}A$$

and note that $M/Q$ is the lower Schur complement of the block matrix

$$
M= 
\begin{bmatrix}
AQ^{-1}A^T & A \\
A^T & Q\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Since $Q$ is positive definite, it follows that $Q^{-1}$ is positive definite and that $Q^{1/2}$ exists. Furthermore $(Q^{-1})^{1/2}$ exists, hence let $Q^{-1/2} := (Q^{-1})^{1/2}.$ Note that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
AQ^{-1}A^T & A \\
A^T & Q\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
AQ^{-1/2} \\
Q^{1/2}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
Q^{-1/2}A^T & Q^{1/2} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Therefore $M$ is positive semidefinite. Since $M$ is positive semidefinite, so too is its lower Schur complement.

Comment: Why does $Q^{-1}$ being positive definite imply that $M$ is positive definite?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you're right; it should be positive SEMIdefinite.

Comment: then why does $Q^{-1}$ being positive definite imply that $M$ is positive semi-definite?  Still don't see it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you for your comment. I've tried to add more detail.

Comment: for non-symmetric matrices, non-negative eigenvalues alone do not imply that the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: Thats a little detail sorry, the matrix $Q$ is also symmetric.

Comment: For instance: the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&10\\0&2}
$$
fails to be positive semidefinite

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see your point.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I've provided an alternate proof which, hopefully, corrects that error.

Comment: Well done! ${}{}{}$

Comment: Why is the positivity of $A$ as the off-diagonal component not necessary for the positivity of $M$ ?